# Form scrolls off page in IE8

Tags: javascript, css, forms, internet-explorer-8

I have a submission form on a landing page that scrolls down and off the page by itself when viewed in IE8.  Is there something I am missing in css that would help prevent this from happening?

The page can be viewed at http://www.borgess.com/files/sem/index.html.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

I see you have this in your code:

```
<!--[if IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css"/> <![endif]-->
```

Go to that file and add this:

```
.form-section {top: 0}
```

---

Let me also give you one more tip:

Your button for Submit has a `filter` ...IE8 will not compute, so for IE8 to be friendly with filter you will need to add `-ms-filter` and obviously you can add that in your ie8.css